Acceder a un setter usando una cadena con su nombre
Estoy haciendo un parseador de un determinado formato de archivo. Se me ha ocurrido utilizar una clase como Modelo, con getters y setters para acceder a las propiedades del objeto.
Ahora necesitaría acceder a un determinado setter usando una cadena que contiene su nombre ... pero como que no
class Prueba:
    def __init__( self ):
        self._value = 0

    @property
    def x( self ):
        return self._value
    @x.setter
    def x( self, value ):
        self._value = value

def test( target, attrName, value ):
    target.attrName = value
    #selector = getattr( target, attrName )
    #selector( target, value )

def main( ):
    p = Prueba( )
    print( "Antes: ", p.x )
    test( p, "x", 10 )
    #p.x = 10
    print( "Después: ", p.x )

main( )


Ese código no genera ningún error, pero muestra

Antes:  0
Después:  0

Cuando lo que yo espero es esto:

Antes:  0
Después:  10

El setter está bien definido, puesto que p.x = 10 si funciona. Pero no encuentro la forma de acceder al setter a través de una cadena con su nombre.

Lo que pasa es que Python no puede manipular directamente un atributo si la referencia a este es una cadena.
En este caso, lo que Python haces es mapear o crear un atributo nuevo con el nombre de la variable attrName. Debido al intrínseco ámbito público de las clases, las mismas pueden ser modificables de esa forma.
Un ejemplo reducido del comportamiento:
class Prueba:
    x = 2
    
P = Prueba
attr = 'x'
P.attr = 6 # <-- Aquí se mapea un nuevo atributo

print(P.x) # 2
print(P.attr) # 6

Solo para contrastar, en otros lenguajes como PHP, si es válido acceder un atributo o un método como cadena:
<?php
class Prueba {
    public int $x = 2;
}

$P = new Prueba;
$attr = 'x';
$P->$attr = 6; // Entiende perfectamente que 'x' es $this->x

echo ($P->x); // Imprime 6
echo ($P->$attr); // Imprime 6


En tu código, en la función test, se adjunta el atributo attrName a la clase. Entonces en la función main(), si imprimes print(dir(p)) verás el nuevo atributo llamado attrName y si le das un print(p.attrName) obtendrás el 10.
Solución: Para asignar valores a un atributo nombrado por cadena, usa el método built-in setattr(). Como se puede deducir tiene su contraparte llamada getattr().
...

def test( target, attrName, value ):
    setattr(target, attrName, value)
    # ...
...


Gracias por el esfuerzo, pero eso no me vale. Si te fijas, en el ejemplo uso una variable interna _value, y se accede a ella a usando el setter. Con lo que indicas, se usaría directamente la variable interna ... sin pasar por el setter. Y es ahí donde va el código de comprobación. Usando setattr( ), no podría validar nada.

@Trauma de hecho no. Se sigue usando el setter, porque en ningún momento se accede a _value desde fuera de la clase. Para la función externa test(), target tiene un "atributo" llamado x, lo cual es la gracia de los decoradores en Python. Si pones un print('...') dentro del setter verás que si lo está usando.

@Trauma setattr(a, b, ...) hace exactamente lo mismo que a.b = ... No existe excepción alguna. Creo que no llegaste a ver como funcionan las propiedades en Python. De hecho, un setter de python de estilo a.b = ... es solo azucar sintactica para a.b(...)

@Trauma excepto para casos muy especiales setattr/getattr/hasattr/delattr es la forma preferible para lidiar con estas situaciones y tal como se ha comentado el setter si que es invocado exactamente igual que cuando se usa dot notation. Hay más formas de hacerlo, menos convenientes, incluidos "esperpentos" como  exec(f"target.{attrName} = value")...
